# Substitute for giving array places properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype

I am trying to make a game that involves saving a list of the active enemies as an array.
Here is my code:

```
function enemyBase(shipRace, shipClass, shipName, health, armour, cloak, regen, speed, dps, suicide, ionImmunity){
this.shipRace = shipRace;
this.shipClass = shipClass;
this.shipName = shipName;
};

function enemy(base, x, y, direction){
this.base = base;
this.x = x;
this.y = y;
this.direction = direction;
};
var enemies = [];

var testDroid = new enemyBase('Test', 'Test', 'EnemyBug', 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, false, false);
var testDroid2 = new enemyBase('Test', 'Test', 'EnemyBug', 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, false, false);
enemies[0] = new enemy(testDroid, 400, 400, 0);
enemies[1] = new enemy(testDroid2, 400, 400, 0);
```

It doesn't work because it can't assign properties directly to a place in the array
I was trying to access it like this:

```
drawEnemy(enemies[0]);
function drawEnemy(enemy){
ctx.translate(enemy.x, enemy.y);
};
```

I could fix this by making an array to store each property and an indexing array but this would take a lot of rewriting.
Can anyone think of a better way?

Comment: Consider using an object with defaults instead a bunch of arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try pushing your enemies to the array:

```
enemies.push(new enemy(testDroid, 400, 400, 0));
enemies.push(new enemy(testDroid2, 400, 400, 0));
```